# ExtJS filter bug with comboboxes

Tags: javascript, extjs, web, filter

I have an issue with my ExtJS application. First the code

```
var typeStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
fields: ['id', 'name'],
data: [
    {id: 1, name: 'type1'},
    {id: 2, name: 'type2'}
]
})

var mainStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
fields: ['id', 'name', 'typeId'],
data: [
    {id: 1, name: 'item1', typeId: 1},
    {id: 2, name: 'item2', typeId: 1},
    {id: 3, name: 'item3', typeId: 2},
    {id: 4, name: 'item4', typeId: 2}
]
})

Ext.application({
name : 'Fiddle',

launch : function() {
    // Ext.Msg.alert('Fiddle', 'Welcome to Sencha Fiddle!');
    Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
        items: [
            Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
                    fieldLabel: 'type',
                    store: typeStore,
                    valueField: 'id',
                    displayField: 'name',
                    listeners: {
                        select: function(combo, records, eOpts)
                        {
                            mainStore.clearFilter();
                            mainStore.filter([
                                Ext.create('Ext.util.Filter',
                                    {
                                        filterFn: function(record)
                                        {
                                            console.dir(record);
                                            var mainId = record.get('id');
                                            var typeId = record.get('typeId');
                                            var type = records[0].get('id');
                                            var tmpRes = (typeId == type);
                                            return tmpRes;
                                        },
                                        root: 'data'
                                    })
                            ])
                        }
                    }
                }),
                Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
                    fieldLabel: 'item',
                    store: mainStore,
                    valueField: 'id',
                    displayField: 'name'
                }) 
        ]
    })

}
});
```

So you have two comboboxes. The value of the first one should filter the second one. 
When you choose an entry in the first one, it filters the second box correctly until you choose an entry in the second one. 
When you change the value in the first one again than no entries are in the second combobox.

Somehow the filter doesn't reset. Do you have any ideas how to solve that problem?

I use ext 4.2.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `queryMode: 'local'`.Here is the updated fiddle: [Simple Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/6mq)

Comment: Thank you very much. It can be that simple :) You solved my headache.